# not able to pass value using ajax in php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am not able to pass value using ajax in php file.

Corrected Code

```
<script>
    $("body").on('change', '#area', function () { 
        //get the selected value 
        var selectedValue = $(this).val(); 
        //make the ajax call 
        $.ajax({
            url: 'box.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {option: selectedValue},
            success: function () {
                console.log("Data sent!");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

here the php code

```
<?php    $val=$_POST['option'];echo $val;    ?>
```

Comment: Please take the time to format your code properly.

Comment: Also note the property in `$.ajax` should be `url:` not `rl:` and you're missing a quote before `POST'`. When you have issues in Javascript, always check the console first.

Comment: and there's a typo in property `type`, a ' is missing

Comment: And `type: POST,` should be `type: 'post',`.

Comment: this.value is wrong it should be $(this).val();

Comment: @chiragchavda.ks no, `this.value` is fine. `this` is a DOMElement and it has `value` property.

Comment: There is a quote `'` missing before `POST`. And please write some explanation to your question so people understand your problem.

Comment: here is my corrected code...<script>
$("body").on('change', '#area', function() {
    //get the selected value
    var selectedValue =  $(this).val();

    //make the ajax call
    $.ajax({
        url: 'box.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {option : selectedValue},
        success: function() {
            console.log("Data sent!");
        }
    });
});
</script>


but still i having the same problem..i have checked in console but it shows the 'data sent' message..i have also checked in network for activity their also it shows the change in activity when i select the drop down value

Comment: So what's the issue? If it says `Data sent!` then it should be working!

Comment: here is my php code.....is their any problem in this 
  <?php
   
    $val=$_POST['option'];
echo $val;
     
    ?>

Comment: and i am geting this Notice: Undefined index: variable in C:\xampp\htdocs\E\box.php on line 3

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems here:

It should be `url`, not `rl`. Also, you have `type: POST'` with it ending in a `'`, but no starting `'`.

It should be `type: 'POST'`.

It should then look like this:

```
$("body").on('change', '#area', function() {      
  var selectedValue = this.value;     
  $.ajax({  
    url: 'box.php', 
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        option : selectedValue
    },     
    success: function() {          
        console.log("Data sent!");    
    }  
  });
});
```

If you want to view your data on the same page after (as on `box.php`, you are `echo`'ing the value.), you can do this:

```
success: function(data) {
  console.log(data);
}
```

This will then write in the console what `option` is, which is the value of `#area`.

Comment: Just a comment, intead of success you can use complete, because you can be interested in checking de data value in spite of query is okey or not

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code

```
$("body").on('change',function(){
  $.ajax({
    URL:<you absolute url>,
    TYPE:POST,
    Data:"variable="+$("#area").val(),
    Success:function(msg){
      <do something>
    }
  });
});
```

Hope this will help you in solving your problem.

Comment: use url, type, data and success in lower case i think i might have used wrong case . and in your php use `$_POST['variable']` or `$_REQUEST['variable']`

Comment: im geting this Notice: Undefined index: variable in C:\xampp\htdocs\E\box.php on line 3

Comment: varialble is synoname for your variable you have to put your variable name in which your data will be send

Comment: and also try to print the POST bject by using `print_r($_POST)`   to see what has been posted by the ajax in that file

Comment: are you sending form data via ajax or some value in html element with id area

Comment: This is my php and html code for dropdown..........

 <?php
  $query = "SELECT distinct area FROM goa"; 
  $result = mysql_query($query); 
  ?>
  <select   name="area" id="area" style="width:180px; max-width:90%;"> 
  <?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?> 
  <option    class="hideoption"> Location</option>  
  <option   value="<?php echo $row['area'];?>"> <?php echo $row['area'];?> </option>  
  <?php } ?> 
  </select>

Answer (score 0):

Your just miss ajax method parameter spelling of 'url' and single quote before value of type i.e. 'POST'. It should be like

```
$.ajax({  
    url: 'box.php', 
    type: 'POST',
    data: {option : selectedValue},     
    success: function() { console.log("Data sent!");}  
});
```